# Is it possible to export 3d Views from Revit model with Design Automation API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I need to create an application, that exports all 3d views of the Revit model to separate rvt file for each model.Is it possible to do with Design Automation API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Say the original model is named A with 3D views V1, V2, ... Vn. Open A. Delete all views except V1. Save as A1. Close A1. Open A. Delete all views except V2. Save as A2. And so on. That can be done in DA4R.

Comment: Thanks.So at first i should  create Revit addin,and than connect it to the Forge?

Comment: i would recommend first creating a Revit desktop add-in for debugging and testing purposes. that can easily be converted to DA4R once it is up and running reliably. here is an example: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/02/preparing-a-revit-add-in-for-design-automation.html. some more hints before getting started with that: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/03/before-getting-started-with-design-automation.html

Comment: The Revit add-in needs to be modified to work in the Forge design automation environment. The code doing the work remains unchanged. The event that you subscribe to in order to trigger the code execution is different. Read the articles I pointed out, please.