# Is it possible to export 3d Views to ifc from Revit model with Design Automation API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I need to create an application, that exports all 3d views of the Revit model to separate rvt file for each model,and after that convert them to an IFC with Model Derivative API.
Suggestion of that problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570909/is-it-possible-to-export-3d-views-from-revit-model-with-design-automation-api)
But,maybe i can directly export 3d Views to an IFC from Design Automation API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Analogously to the previous answer
on [exporting 3D Revit views with Design Automation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570909/is-it-possible-to-export-3d-views-from-revit-model-with-design-automation-api):

Say the original model is named A with 3D views V1, V2, ... Vn.

- Open A.
- Delete all views except V1.
- Exort to A1.ifc using the [Document.Export method taking IFC options](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/7efa4eb3-8d94-b8e7-f608-3dbae751331d.htm)
- Close A.

Repeat for all the other reeuired views.

Initially, DA4R did not provide full support for IFC export, but I believe that should be possible now.

Comment: Could i upload to BIM360 Docs those converted  IFC files,or i should firstly download them on the computer?

Comment: I'm checking with more knowledgeable colleagues to answer that for you... hang on...